# How to fix Deploying cordapp to corda node in testnet error

Tags: corda

I deployed a corda node to corda testnet and I built my sample coded cordapp and copied the jars to the corda node cordapp folder and ran the node and It loaded the workflow (Workflow Cordapp : Template Flows) jar but not the contract (CorDapp Template Contract) jar. The node also is running in production mode. When I do POST requests to the node. It shows error

I configured the contract build.gradle file and turn the signing to false.

**This is the node error and the logs:**

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you share your error in your question rather than linking to it.

Comment: It is a run time issue. Can you go into debug mode, and upload some logs, (especially looking for exceptions)

Comment: The log says that the "workflows-0.1.jar" is signed with development keys. As the cordapp is running in production mode, you may have to use production keys. Or you may run by disabling the signing options.

To run the server by disabling the signing options, use the following command - 

**gradlew.bat -Dsigning.enabled=false _servername_**

Answer (score 0):

I believe Devman is correct, in this case, you can't just build cordapps on your local machine and then try to use them for the Corda testnet without some additional changes. You'll need to build and sign your apps with the production keys.

There are a few things you'll have to do with local machine configuration and networking.

Here's the corda docs page on the topic: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/deploy-locally.html